# Thumbnail slider using slick.js with distorted position

Tags: slider, slick.js

I'm working on a thumbnail slider using slick.js. It works fine with the sliders but positioning is distorted. Tried to realign it properly but was struck at locating the exact area to pick.

```
`https://codepen.io/isarathk/pen/JaBoaR`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing some time with Slick Sliders, i finally met the requirement.
The codepen link has been posted below for reference.

We can use two sliders with 'asNavFor' attribute included which appends the functionality of one slider movement to other while navigation is shown for both the sliders.

The codepen link given in the question has been modified with the answer, for reference.